# Merge two videos side by side programmatically

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, gstreamer

I need to merge two avi videos side by side and I succeeded with python + gstreamer as below code.

```
pipe = """
videomixer2 name=mix background=1 
  sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=60 sink_0::zorder=0 
  sink_1::xpos=640 sink_1::ypos=60 sink_1::zorder=0 !
ffmpegcolorspace name=colorsp_saida ! 
video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)I420, width=1280, height=480, framerate=25/1 ! 
x264enc quantizer=45 speed-preset=6 profile=1 ! queue ! 
mp4mux name=mux  ! queue ! filesink location="output.mp4"

filesrc location="video1.avi" ! decodebin2 name=dbvideo1 ! 
aspectratiocrop aspect-ratio=16/9 ! videoscale ! videorate ! 
ffmpegcolorspace name=colorsp_video1 ! 
video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)AYUV, framerate=25/1, width=640, height=360 ! 
mix.sink_0 

filesrc location="video2.avi" ! decodebin2 name=dbvideo2 ! 
aspectratiocrop aspect-ratio=16/9 ! videoscale ! videorate ! 
ffmpegcolorspace name=colorsp_video2 ! 
video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)AYUV, framerate=25/1, width=640, height=360 ! 
mix.sink_1 
"""

import gst
pipeline = gst.Pipeline()
bus = pipeline.get_bus()

gst_bin = gst.parse_bin_from_description(pipe, False)
pipeline.add(gst_bin)

pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered(gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE, gst.MESSAGE_ERROR | gst.MESSAGE_EOS)
pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
```

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS, python 2.7 and gstreamer.

I have few issues as below,

- when I use bigger input files(duration more than 30 minutes) program is hang on lator stage, but still its giving the output.mp4.
- this is very slow, if I convert 30 minutes, program also running for 20 -25 minutes
- two input files may have few seconds(10-20 seconds) time gap, will it be the issue?

If I have any other way to merge and convert this files, other than gstreamer also acceptable.

**UPDATE 1:**

After few days of works I found that program get hang on `pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)` line. Anyone have an idea ,how to overcome this.

Basically I need to free the resources of pipeline without any trouble.

**UPDATE 2:**

I need to merge two video(avi) files(either file will have a audio) side by side and convert to MP4 format, is a whole idea of this question. I tried with gstreamer and stuck on a place that I have described in above.

Comment: Did you try with gstreamer 1.0? 0.10 is not maintained anymore. The pipeline should be the same. Just replace ffmpegcolorspace with videoconvert, decodebin2 with decodebin and videomixer2 with videomixer. Also you need to use the new pygi bindings instead of the python gst module. This can give you some hints: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Novacut/GStreamer1.0

Comment: I use gstreamer 0.10 and i will try those steps

Comment: due to some reasons I can't change the version and I have to keep the 0.10 for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working `ffmpeg` code,

```
./ffmpeg -i video1.avi -i video2.avi -r 30 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640:480, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, pad=1280:720:0:120[left]; [1:v]scale=640:480, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, pad=640:720:0:120[right]; [left][right]overlay=w; amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive ffmpeg may be a bit faster, take a look at these links:

http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-June/015662.html
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide#multipleinputoverlayin2x2grid

There is ffmpeg wrapper for python:

https://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/

Comment: I tried with ffmpeg but it doesn't give me proper results, Actually I can't mix the audio with that.